# About Using shortcode in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin called serp shaker. In this plugin there is option to create shortcode for any given content.

i.e 
the shortcode name is test-short
the content is`This is a short code generated paragraph in p tag`

Now if I put [ssad ssadblk="test-short"] in post it gets the p tag content.

I want to use short-code into the content area.

i.e
the short-code name is test-short
the content is [shake-post]

[shake-post] is a short-code which has per-defined content. 
But wordpress does not take the [shake-post] as a short-code. It takes it as content.

How can I use [shake-post] as short-code?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you use `the_content();`
or `do_shortcode(get_the_content());`
or `apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());`

get_the_content() doesn't apply the shortcodes